# How to make keyword fixed at center while left and right parts stay close to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A sentence contains 3 parts, left-part keyword and right part.
I need to realize the keyword fixed at one vertical line while two other parts  stay close to it .
I realized it through make them positon absolute , but the length of key word not the same .
And it will show like picture below.
How to make it flexible?
My method is like this:

```
 .left-part{
       position: absolute;
       right : 300px;
       text-align: right;
    }
 .right-part{
       position: absolute;
       left : 200px;
 }
 .keyword{
       margin: 0 50%;
 }
```

too long
[image: too long]
normal one
[image: normal one]
too short
[image]

Comment: could you show the not expected behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear . I just added the image

Comment: @yaochiqkl good edit. Now it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display:table;` (or also CSS3's `flex-box`)

**Using `table` set the first cell and last one to width `50%`.**
I know 50% + 50% makes 100% but table will handle the middle's cell width automatically for you:

```css
.table{
  display:         table;
  width:           100%;
}
.row {
  display:         table-row;
}
.row span {
  display:         table-cell;
  padding:         8px;
  border-bottom:   1px solid #ddd; 
}
.row span:first-child {
  text-align:      right;
  width:           50%;              /* FIRST CELL TO 50% */
}
.row span:last-child {
  width:           50%;              /* LAST CELL TO 50% */
}
.row span:nth-child(2) {
  color:           red;              /* MIDDLE CELL*/
                                     /* LEAVE WIDTH UNTOUCHED */
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div class="row">
    <span>ACDC</span>
    <span>DANGEROUS</span>
    <span>Back in Black</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <span>DJ StackOverflow</span>
    <span>DANGEROUS</span>
    <span>foobar</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <span>Antonio Vivaldi</span>
    <span>DANGEROUS</span>
    <span>Four Seasons</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

<sub>is that what you meant?</sub>

Comment: Amazing  Thx a lot! I'll try it later! :D